# Unknown numbers sending videos on WhatsApp. What should I do?

Tags: account-security, whatsapp, fraud, scam

A number with ISD code +92 sent a video via WhatsApp. No text, only a video. About 20 days later, another number with same ISD sent another video.

**Should I open the video?**

OR

**Should I Report and Block?**

Moreover, a family member received the videos as well but from different numbers but same ISD. Can't say if we have been sent the same videos as the durations (as seen from notifications) are different. That's all I know.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the sender of the videos, I personally would not open anything. You could theoretically open the videos in an isolated environment where the impact if it is harmful is lower, but I would not open it on any device, in any environment where it could do serious damage. With that said, fight your curiosity! :)

Answer (score 2):

Videos and images have long been used against smartphone users to hack their devices.

The best you could do is to delete the entire conversations and block the numbers.

Make sure your phone is fully updated and don't skimp on OS updates.

Answer (score 2):

The best course of action when receiving messages from unknown numbers is to block and delete. Especially so if they are sending you any kind of media. It is also best to NOT open the media because it could contain malware. Do not respond to the message because it lets them know that your number is active and potentially a good target for further spam.